# ASP.NET Identity 2 initializer drop all my tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identity,  2.21 version. As soon as my AppDbInitializer is triggered in Global.asax, all tables in LibraryContext are deleted. So I get SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Books' error. I think, the problem is in my initializers, but don't know where. All tables use the same "DefaultConnection" string.

**My LibraryContext and initializer:**

```
public class Library : DbContext
{
    public Library(string connectionString)
       : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new LibraryDbInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }        
}

public class LibraryDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Library>
{
    protected override void Seed(Library db)
    {
        //shortened for brevity
        base.Seed(db);
    }
}
```

**Identity initializer:**

```
public class AppDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        var role1 = new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" };
        var role2 = new IdentityRole { Name = "user" };

        roleManager.Create(role1);
        roleManager.Create(role2);

        var admin = new ApplicationUser { Email = "somemail@mail.ru", UserName = "somemail@mail.ru" };
        string password = "ad46D_ewr3";
        var result = userManager.Create(admin, password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, role1.Name);
            userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, role2.Name);
        }

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you have used DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Library>, this will always deletes all the tables and database and will create it again. Where are you getting the sqlException?

Comment: After login to the system and attempts to read books from the table of the book. Here: return _dbSet.ToList();

Comment: I tried all types of initializer(DropCreateDatabaseAlways for example), but it didn't work anyway.

Comment: don't invoke 'base.Seed(context);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed DropCreateDatabaseAlways for CreateDatabaseIfNotExists here:.

```
public class AppDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>// DropCreateDatabaseAlways was
```

And now it's working!)